# Is there any way to add 3 (multiple) radio button in <mat-table> each row?. using mat-radio-button

Tags: angular

I am adding multiple radio button (3 radio buttons) in .
Data is binding dynamic in . Only one radio button should be selected in each row.

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <!-- <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson"> -->
      <mat-radio-button checked  value="1">View</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button value="2" >View/Edit</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button value="3" >No Access</mat-radio-button>
    <!-- </mat-radio-group> -->
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Why comment **mat-radio-group** ?